# Firebase Nuxt module only on specific pages?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am including @nuxtjs/firebase in my nuxt.config.js, but only using Firebase auth and other features on specific routes. However, by including the Firebase module in nuxt.config.js it's loading a bunch of code that is not needed by other pages and negatively affecting site performance (per Lighthouse).

How can I only load this module for the pages that need it?

Comment: Was searching exactly this scenario today. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'lazy' option in your nuxt.config.js:

```
modules: [
[
  '@nuxtjs/firebase',
  {
    config: {
      apiKey: 'somerandomkey', ...
    },
    services: {
      firestore: true,
    },
    lazy: true,
  },
],],
```

Then when you are ready to use the feature, you can manually load it:

```
await this.$fire.firestoreReady()
```

https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/options/#lazy